# How can i use IDR

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, state-machine

I am trying to make an state machine with button. When i press the button, state will change. But I can not read the button from IDR. How can i read the button press with IDR ? if( GPIOA->IDR |= (1U << 1) ) this part has a problem i think or should i enable some registers or clocks ?

`

```
int main(void) {

    uint32_t ButtonPress = 0;

    /* Enable GPIOA clock */
    RCC->IOPENR |= (1U << 0);

    /* Setup PA0 as output */
    GPIOA->MODER &= ~(3U << 2*0);
    GPIOA->MODER |= (1U << 2*0);

    /* Setup PA1 as input */
    GPIOA->MODER &= ~(3U << 2*1);
    GPIOA->MODER |= (0U << 2*1);

    /* Setup PA1 as Button1 */
//    GPIOA->IDR |= (1U << 1);


    while(1) {

        if( GPIOA->IDR |= (1U << 1) )
            ButtonPress++;

        if(ButtonPress == 0)
            /* Turn off LED */
            GPIOA->ODR ^= (1U << 0);

        else if(ButtonPress == 1){
            /* Turn on LED 2sec interval */
            GPIOA->ODR |= (1U << 0);
            delay(LEDDELAY);
            delay(LEDDELAY);
            GPIOA->ODR ^= (1U << 0);
            delay(LEDDELAY);
            delay(LEDDELAY);
        }

        else if(ButtonPress == 2){
            /* Turn on LED 1sec interval */
            GPIOA->ODR |= (1U << 0);
            delay(LEDDELAY);
            GPIOA->ODR ^= (1U << 0);
            delay(LEDDELAY);
        }

        else if(ButtonPress == 3){
            /* Turn on LED 0.5sec interval */
            GPIOA->ODR |= (1U << 0);
            delay(LEDDELAY/2);
            GPIOA->ODR ^= (1U << 0);
            delay(LEDDELAY/2);
        }

        else if(ButtonPress == 4){
            /* Turn on LED 0.1sec interval */
            GPIOA->ODR |= (1U << 0);
            delay(LEDDELAY/10);
            GPIOA->ODR ^= (1U << 0);
            delay(LEDDELAY/10);
        }

        else if(ButtonPress == 5){
            /* Turn on LED */
            GPIOA->ODR |= (1U << 0);
        }

        else
            /* Button Reset */
            ButtonPress = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`

I am trying to make an state machine with button. When i press the button, state will change. But I can not read the button from IDR.

Comment: Why do you use `|=`? That's assignment, and the result of `GPIOA->IDR |= (1U << 1)` will always be "true".

Comment: You are right. But there are 16 IDR registers. My button is IDR1 how can i see the IDR1 ?

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but use bitwise and `&` to check if the bit is set? As in `(GPIOA->IDR & (1U << 1)) == (1U << 1)`? Be careful though, as pressing and *holding* the button will increase `ButtonPress` quite rapidly. You might want to add a state for the button itself, so you increase `ButtonPress` only once when the button is pressed, and reset the state when the button is released.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to write to the `IDR` with this line

> ```c
> if( GPIOA->IDR |= (1U << 1) )
> ```

Since the `IDR` is read-only, the statement always evaluates to false.

Instead, you should use:

```c
if (GPIOA->IDR & GPIO_PIN_1) { // GPIO_PIN_1 is a macro for (1U << 1)
    ButtonPress++;
}
```

to evaluate the value of GPIOA pin 1.